# Filter on through table in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Does Django support filtering on a through table? I havent had any luck with this so far.

I have the following three models:

```
class TeamMember(models.Model):
    member_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField()

class Report(models.Model):
    report_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    report_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class Owner(models.Model):
    teammember = models.ForeignKey(TeamMember, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    primary_owner = models.IntegerField()
```

And would like to filter based on the primary owner flag (either 1 or 0) to get the single person who is a primary owner of that report.

I have tried:

```
owners = TeamMember.objects.filter(report__id=id,primary_owner__contains=1).distinct()[:1]
```

Alhtough this doesnt work.

Comment: Why are you using __contains? primary_owner is an integer, not a string.

Comment: I thought contains works for all? None the less it cant find primary owner in this case

Comment: Works for all what? __contains maps to an IN operator in SQL.

Comment: But yes, primary_owner is not a field on TeamMember, it is a field on Owner. You already know how to traverse the relationship for report, why not for owner as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your starting point is a `TeamMember`, a `teammember` has reverse relation to `Owner` which you need to use in order to filter on `Owner.report` and `Owner.primary_owner` bit.

e.g.

```
owners = TeamMember.objects.filter(
    owner__report_id=id, #its also possible to use: owner__report__id
    owner__primary_owner=1 #I have no idea why you use contains on an IntegerField?
).distinct()[:1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
primary_owner = TeamMember.objects.filter(owner__report__id=id,
                                          owner__primary_owner=1).first()
```

The model name `Owner` is a bit missleading, what about `ReportOwnership` (or suggest any other!). Also, primary_owner should be a `BooleanField`